# How can I detect if there is a webcam connected to the PC?

Tags: winapi, vb6

I have the source code for taking a picture via webcam, but I need to know if there's a webcam connected to the PC. If there's no webcam, the program won't call the function for taking photos. If necessary, I need to know which window's Api I have to use in this case.

Language: Visual Basic 6 using windows Apis.

Comment: What does the "function for taking photos" use to take photos? which API does it use?

Comment: I use these two Apis: SendMessage and capCreateCaptureWindowA. For "Taking photos" I meant capturing a frame from a webcam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the WIA is that not all devices are compatible. But I found the solution myself:
SendMessage and capCreateCaptureWindowA work together. If there's no camera, SendMessage returns a "0". This is the code:

imports:

```
'This code is in Module1.bas
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public Declare Function capCreateCaptureWindow Lib "avicap32.dll" Alias "capCreateCaptureWindowA" (ByVal lpszWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal nID As Long) As Long

Public Const WM_USER = 1024
Public Const WM_CAPCONNECT As Long = 1034
Public Const DISCONNECT As Long = 1035
Public Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW = WM_USER + 50
Public mCapHwnd As Long
```

Code:

```
mCapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, Me.hwnd, 0)
DoEvents
If SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0) <> 0 Then
Call SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0)
DoEvents
Call SendMessage(mCapHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, 0, 0)
Else
MsgBox "No Camera Detected"
End If
```

I hope somebody can find this useful :)

Comment: Which LIB are you using ? No imports,No Declare, No Functions ?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a flash app for that, if you're working on a website.  Otherwise you might want to look into the Windows Image Acquisition API.

Comment: Nope, it is a desktop app. I've seen the code for flash, but I need it for VB6. Not the entire algorithm, just the Api that can detect the webcam.

Comment: Take a look at the WIA api, then.